# Дамп всех переменных в php скрипте

Tags: php

Отлатчики советовать не нужно, вопрос заключается в другом.

Как это выглядит с точки зрения реализации?:

Написать функцию, которая будет открывать сам файл со скриптом, где он вызывается, и парсить названия всех переменных до того места, где вызывается функция, и делать дамп для каждой переменной?

Comment: А какие переменные имеются ввиду. Есть конечно GLOBALS: http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.globals.php но в нем понятное дело только глобальные переменные. А локальные переменные доступны только внутри тех областей видимости, где они объявлены и вне этой области видимости до них добраться невозможно

Comment: Почему невозможно?

Предположим есть функция `deb()`, которая при первом вызове, открывает файл со скриптом, где он вызывается, парсит с файла все переменные, и глобальные, и локальные, создает массив из всех этих переменных и записывает в сессию. А при последующих вызовах функции, будет выводится дамп для каждой переменной из массива которую записали в сессию.

Comment: Что значит "парсит переменные" ? получает их имена ? И что даст имя переменной. предположим у меня есть функция `function test() { $a="Hello"; }` ваш скрипт конечно имя этой переменной получит. Узнает что существует `$a`, но за пределами функции test обращаться по этому имени бесполезно - она не существует за пределами test.

Comment: Да, узнать название переменной, если не существует этой переменной выводить undefined.
Если нам нужно будет сделать дамп переменных, которые в ` test()` можно эту функцию `deb()` вызывать в самой функции `test()`

Comment: Да, только просто вызвать из `test` `deb` бесполезно, надо явно передать внутрь `deb` эти переменные. Попробуйте `function deb() { print $a; } function test() { $a="Hello"; deb(); }` У вас будет ошибка несуществующей переменной при попытке печати, ибо переменная _локальная_ и ее область видимости - только ее функция. Максимум что может сделать ваш парсер - сам расставлять в коде кучу строк типа `deb("a=$a b=$b ...");` и в каких местах он должен их ставить ?

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глобальные переменные вы можете получить в [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.globals.php). А до локальных вы, к сожалению, не доберетесь, т.к. они доступны только в контексте, где используются. Рассмотрим пример:

```
function test()
 {
  $a="World";
  deb();
 }
function deb()
 {
  print "Hello ";
  print $a;
 }

test();
```

Данный пример напечатает только Hello, т.к. в функции `deb()` переменная `$a` не доступна, даже не смотря на то, что `deb()` вызван из `test()`.

Единственный способ получить значения локальных переменных, это явно передать их функции логирования, как параметры `deb("a=$a b=$b ...")` из того контекста в котором они были объявлены.